# View pulls up all table records instead of specific ID records, controller issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build a simple quiz app, I already have one table for questions and another for answers (answers each have a question_id tag to pull up the multiple choice options for each question).

I have listed out all my multiple choice questions on one page, and I want only the answers that correspond to each question to display below the question, however each MCQ is currently listing the full answer table instead of just the matching answers.

I think it has to do either with my view or controller code that's causing this behaviour (when I change the question ID in my controller to just a single question, the 4 possible answers appear correctly, but when I change it to `@questions = Question.all`, then the full answer table returns).

Or it might have to do with using `<% @question_answers.each do |question_answers| %>` wrongly.

My pages_controller.rb code:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
  end

  def home

  end

  def challenge
    @questions = Question.all
    @question_answers = QuestionAnswer.where(question_id: @questions.pluck(:id))
    # @questions = Question.where(id: 3)
  end
end
```

My view file at pages/challenge.html.erb:

```
<h1>Challenge</h1>

<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<div class="container">
    <p><%= question.question %></p>
    <form>
      <% @question_answers.each do |question_answers| %>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value=<%= question_answers.answer %>><%= question_answers.answer %><br>
      <% end %>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

I want only the answers that correspond to each question to display below the question, any ideas what I'm getting wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong with this code:

```
<% @question_answers.each do |question_answers| %>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value=<%= question_answers.answer %>><%= question_answers.answer %><br>
<% end %>
```

`question_answers` is all records from answer table because you assigned it to `QuestionAnswer.where(question_id: @questions.pluck(:id))`

You should query only questions that belongs to answer. Assume you have two model and set up association like this:

```
class Question
  has_many :question_answers
end

class QuestionAnswer
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Then in your view you can get questions belongs to an answer like this:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<div class="container">
  ...
  <% question.question_answers.each do |question_answer| %>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value=<%= question_answer.answer %>><%= question_answer.answer %><br>
  <%>
  ...
</div>
<% end %>
```

In controller, you only need:

```
@questions = Question.includes(:question_answers).all
```

`includes(:question_answers)` is used to avoid N+1 queries when loading answers for each question.

Comment: Thanks Thanh for the in-depth answer, the controller refactoring works great! I had already defined the relationship between the models earlier (which matched what you suggested), your changes to the view and controller really helped improve my code, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the relationship between the models `question` and `answer`.
If so, in the view try giving this

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
<div class="container">
    <p><%= question.question %></p>
    <form>
      <% question.question_answers.each do |question_answers| %>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value=<%= question_answers.answer %>><%= question_answers.answer %><br>
      <% end %>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<% end %>
```

when you give `question.question_answers.each` the answers related to that question will be pulled.

Comment: Thank you Nandhini! That solved it exactly to do what I wanted, still trying to understand why what you provided worked, but thanks very much all the same!